# How To Create A Fluid Height Div?

Tags: css

Note: I'm still learning CSS & HTML, so if this question seems "noobish" - that's because it is.  If you could provide an example, or an article geared towards my questions that would be great.

I created a div ("background"), which contains two divs ("left" & "right").

I'd like the "background" div's height to expand or contract, based up the amount of content in the "left" & "right" div.

```
#background {
width:100%;
height:15em;
background-color:#FFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
clear:both;
}
```

I currently have the "background" div's height set to 15em, because I'm not sure how to make it expand or contract.  I've tried setting it to "100%" and "auto", but those just make the "background" div disappear.

Here is my entire HTML & CSS code: http://jsfiddle.net/jueRh/

Answer (score 5):

Set `overflow: hidden;` in `#background` and remove the `height:15em;` declaration.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sonic1980/jueRh/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you leave your container `div` without a `height` value, it will become an extendable container to it's content.

If you still want your `div` to have a certain height, but expand on overflown content, you can use `min-height`. Also do note that `min-height` is only supported by equal or above [enlisted browsers in this link.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

**EDIT:** However, if you'll be using `float`ed `div`s inside the container, you will have to `clear` the float for proper rendering. You can also use `display:inline-block` for a `float` alternative, which then you can skip the `clear`ing, but [that is also support limited.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)